# NotesException: Unknown or unsupported object type in Vector

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, domino-designer-eclipse, ssjs

I'm trying to add new names to the address book programmatically but I'm getting the following error:

> [TypeError] Exception occurred calling method NotesDocument.replaceItemValue(string, Array)
>   Unknown or unsupported object type in Vector

Code snippet below:

```
var addressBook = session.getDatabase("","names.nsf");
var gView:NotesView = addressBook.getView("($VIMGroups)");
var gDoc:NotesDocument = gView.getDocumentByKey("groupName", true);

var newg:java.util.Vector = [];
var mems:java.util.Vector = new Array(gDoc.getItemValue('Members'));
newg.push(mems);

var newNames:java.util.Vector = new Array(getComponent("NewMems").getValue());
newg.push(newNames);

gDoc.replaceItemValue("Members", newg);
gDoc.save();
```

Adding a single user works fine, but then it does not save users in the required canonical format below:

> CN=John Doe/O=Org

Instead it is saved in the original format below:

> John Doe/Org

I look forward to your suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't store an Array in a field. Make `newg` a java.util.Vector instead and integrate with that.

For OpenNTF Domino API the team wrote a lot of code to auto-convert to Vectors, which may cover Arrays.

Comment: Yes, I have now added types to the variable but still getting same results.

Comment: Thats because you're declaring it as a Vector but initialising it as an Array. So it's still an Array.

Comment: Looping and push values seems to produce the desired result. Many thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an Array (which is a JS thing). Initialize it as a Vector.

var newg:java.util.Vector = new java.util.Vectory();

Then look up the Vector methods to see how to add to that vector. Not sure if you will have to convert the names using the Name method but I would store them as "CN=Joe Smith/O=Test Org" to be sure you got the right format.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue using a forloop to loop through the list and push it into a newly created array. Using the forloop seems to make the difference.

```
var newg = [];
var group = new Array(getComponent("NewMems").getValue()), lenGA = group.length;
for(i = 0; i < lenGA; i++){
   newg.push(group[i]);
}
gDoc.replaceItemValue("Members", newg);
gDoc.save();
```

An explanation about this behaviour will be appreciated.